# Which Android API to use in libGDX Android SDK manager?

Tags: libgdx

I am installing Java framework libGDX and In the Android SDK Manager I have to install an Android API, which Android API should I install? Maybe API 21 (Android 5.0) or any older like Android API 19 (Android 4.4.2) and Android API 8 (Android 2.2)? I want to make games and then post it on Google Play.

Thank you for your reply and help.

Comment: If using the latest libgdx, set `android:minSdkVersion` to 8 and `android:targetSdkVersion` to the latest available SDK, which is what you should compile with. A libgdx app doesn't use much cutting edge Android API, but you should target the latest version to get immersive mode working correctly on devices that support it..

Comment: So I should use min SDK 8 and target SDK 20/21 (4.4/5.0) for libGDX?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the Android version market share: [Platform Versions](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

Have a look also [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html#Versions) [this talks about the manifest used by an android app]

> The API level allows you to declare the minimum version with which
>   your app is compatible, using the  manifest tag and its
>   minSdkVersion attribute.
>
> For example, the Calendar Provider APIs were added in Android 4.0 (API
>   level 14). If your app cannot function without these APIs, you should
>   declare API level 14 as your app's minimum supported version like
>   this:

When I created the libgdx [I have the Android 4.3 SDK installed] it created the manifest file [ **AndroidManifest.xml** ] with:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

And the 8 means from 2.2 onward, the app that are created are compatible then with 2.2 and greater.

Comment: What is the best option for the widest spectrum of users?

Comment: Have a look at the graph in the first link.

Comment: hello, SDK API version 21 has an error in aapt.exe now a library, at least to me gave me that error, grabbing four days, so use the API 19